# Object with attributes of any type with easy storage and iteration

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I have an "object" with different attributes stored as key/value. The key is a string and the value can be any basic type. My first idea was using a template class:

```
template <class T>
class Attribute {
public:
    Attribute<T>(const std::string& key, T value) :
        m_key(key),
        m_value(value)
    {
    }

    ~Attribute(){}

    T getValue() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    std::string getKey() const
    {
        return m_key;
    }
private:
    std::string m_key;
    T m_value;
};
```

But now the problem is that in my object class, I have to declare fields and overload functions for each possible attribute type:

```
class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject(int value) :
        m_value(value)
    {
    }

    ~MyObject()
    {
    }

    int getValue() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    void addAttribute(Attribute<int> attribute)
    {
        m_intAttributes.push_back(attribute);
    }

    void addAttribute(Attribute<double> attribute)
    {
        m_doubleAttributes.push_back(attribute);
    }

    const std::list<Attribute<int> >& getIntAttributes() const
    {
        return m_intAttributes;
    }

    const std::list<Attribute<double> >& getDoubleAttributes() const
    {
        return m_doubleAttributes;
    }

private:
    int m_value;
    std::list<Attribute<int> > m_intAttributes;
    std::list<Attribute<double> > m_doubleAttributes;
};
```

Moreover, iterating through the attributes is not very comfortable and looking for an attribute of a given name is very difficult:

```
void showMyObject(const MyObject& myObject)
{
    std::list<Attribute<int> > intAttributes;
    std::list<Attribute<int> >::const_iterator itInt;
    std::list<Attribute<double> > doubleAttributes;
    std::list<Attribute<double> >::const_iterator itDouble;

    std::cout << "Value in myObject " << myObject.getValue() << std::endl;

    intAttributes = myObject.getIntAttributes();
    for(itInt = intAttributes.begin() ; itInt != intAttributes.end() ; itInt++)
    {
        std::cout << itInt->getKey() << " = " << itInt->getValue() << std::endl;
    }

    doubleAttributes = myObject.getDoubleAttributes();
    for(itDouble = doubleAttributes.begin() ; itDouble != doubleAttributes.end() ; itDouble++)
    {
        std::cout << itDouble->getKey() << " = " << itDouble->getValue() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

FYI, my main function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyObject object(123);

    object.addAttribute(Attribute<double>("testDouble", 3.23));
    object.addAttribute(Attribute<double>("testDouble2", 99.654));
    object.addAttribute(Attribute<int>("testInt", 3));
    object.addAttribute(Attribute<int>("testInt2", 99));

    showMyObject(object);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess if we want to guarantee type safety, there **must be** somewhere list of functions with the right return type in the signature (getTYPEAttributes in my example).

However, I was wondering if a more elegant solution exists and if a design pattern I'm not aware of could help me to handle this problem correctly.

Comment: You can do that with base class for all Attributes and `dynamic_cast` on `get`. Something like `attribute->getValue<int>()`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::list`?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, any>` seems to be what you're designing, where "any" is `boost::any` or `std::experimental::any`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! std::map seems the way to go, I used an "Attribute" class because I wanted to encapsulate this Template thing ... I've never heard about the std::any, I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html). You want to store different kinds of things that share common traits (are streamable, have a key), but can be explicitly accessed and don't need a common base? Store your attributes thusly:

```
namespace mpl = boost::mpl
using namespace boost::type_erasure;

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_getKey), getKey, 0)

using AnyAttribute = any<mpl::vector<
                         copy_constructible<>,
                         typeid_<>,
                         ostreamable<>, // add a stream operator for Attribute
                         has_getKey<std::string(), const _self>
                         > >;

std::vector<AnyAttribute> attributes;
```

Adding an attribute would look like:

```
template <typename T>
void addAttribute(const std::string& key, const T& value) {
    // since Attribute<T> is copy-constructible, streamable,
    // and has a member function with the signature std::string getKey() const
    // we can construct an AnyAttribute with it.
    attributes.push_back(Attribute<T>(key, value));
}
```

Printing all of the attributes:

```
void showMe() {
    for (const auto& attr : attributes) {
        std::cout << attr << ' '; // since we specified ostreamable<>,
                                  // everything we put into this any<> is streamable
                                  // so the any<> is too
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Looking up an attribute by name and specified type, returns `nullptr` if not found or wrong type:

```
template <typename T>
const Attribute<T>* lookupAttribute(const std::string& key) {
    // can use getKey() even if they're all different types
    // because we added has_getKey<> as a concept
    auto it = std::find_if(attributes.begin(), attributes.end(), 
        [=](const AnyAttribute& a) {
            return a.getKey() == key;
        }); 

    if (it != attributes.end()) {
        // this will return a valid Attribute<T>* you specified the
        // correct type, nullptr if you specified the incorrect type
        // it is not possible to query the type.
        return any_cast<Attribute<T>*>(&*it);
    }   
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }   
}
```

There's a simpler type-erased object which is just [`Boost.Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html), but there you cannot have any kind of common functionality - which would make it difficult to implement either the lookup or the printing operations I illustrated above.

Comment: You could also store this in a `std::map` instead of a `vector`, I just put it into a `vector` to demonstrate lookup by `getKey()`.

Comment: Each time I adventure into the forest of boost I meet mysticcal beasts and magicians. I'm wondering how long it will take me to understand what the code really does but I like this solution pretty much!

Comment: @anxieux We declared our `AnyAttribute` to implement the `ostreamable<>` concept. That enforces that whatever we construct an `AnyAttribute` with must be able to be streamed, and also adds a stream operator to `AnyAttribute`'s interface which will know enough about its internal type to know how to forward along the `operator<<` call to the right cast of its internal storage. tldr; it's complicated.

Comment: Do you know how much size does it add to each object?

Comment: @anxieux It does not add size to each object. It holds pointers to them internally. When you add an `Attribute<int>`, there is an actual `Attribute<int>` living on the heap somewhere. `sizeof(AnyAttribute)` itself is 32 - but can handle *any* object that satisfies the listed concepts.

Comment: It has to resolve at runtime which `operator<<` to call. Thus it has to store the identifier of the underlying type somewhere, right?

Comment: @anxieux It has to store something, yes. You can look up the code. It's incredibly hard to understand - but everything is there... somewhere...

Comment: . . . . . . . . . . . Wow.